# Where has 'Exclude URL query parameters' gone in GA4

Tags: google-analytics-4, google-analytics-filters

GA4 has removed Views. DAK where ‘*Exclude URL query parameters*’ (that is needed to remove Facebook’s fbclid) now lives  - if at all?